# TensorFlow unexpected behaviour

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
y = tf.Variable(initial_value=[1,2])
sess.run(y, feed_dict={y: [100,2]})
```

Gives:
    [100,2]

However, after that:

```
sess.run(y)
```

Gives the origianl value of y: [1,2].

Why doesn't the:

```
sess.run(y, feed_dict={y: [100,2]})
```

updates the value of y, and saves it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `feed_dict` overrides the values of the keys of the dictionary.

With the statement:

```
sess.run(y, feed_dict={y: [100,2]})
```

you're telling tensorflow to replace the values of `y` with `[100, 2]` **for the current computation**. This is not an assignment.

Therefore, the next call

```
sess.run(y)
```

fetches the original variables and uses it.

If you want to assign a value to a variable, you have to define this operation in the computational graph, using [`tf.assing`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#assign)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a feed dictionary, initialize a placeholder instead of a variable and define the output.

As an example (in the same style as your question code),

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape = (2,2))
output = tf.matmul(inputs, tf.transpose(inputs))

test_input = np.array([[10,2], [4,4]])
print test_input.shape
# (2,2)

sess.run(output, feed_dict = {inputs : test_input})
# array([[104, 48], [48, 32]], dtype=int32)
```

If you just want to change the value of a variable look to nessuno's answer.